# Azure Durable Function Task Activity Exception: Deserializer Exception: Too many characters

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an Activity function that loads around 1 GB of data (100 K rows), and returns it as JSON message.

**It throws exception:
"Failed to deserialize exception from TaskActivity: Unhandled exception while executing task: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Too many characters. The resulting number of bytes is larger than what can be returned as an int.**

> **Starter Function:**

```
`async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
response_obj = client.create_check_status_response(req,instance_id)
response_str = response_obj.get_body().decode("utf-8")
response = json.loads(response_str)`
```

> **Orchestrator Function:**

```
def loader(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):**
    try:
        result = yield context.call_activity('UAT-Activity', "")
        return result
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

> **Activity Function:**

```
def main(name: str) -> str:
  df = load() ## This returns a large pandas with 1 GB of data
  return df.to_json(orient = 'records', force_ascii=True)
```

> **Local.setting.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=stuksuat02;AccountKey=XXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python"
  }
}
```

> **Host.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "storageProvider": {
        "connectionStringName": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
        "partitionCount": 3
      },
      "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 10,
      "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 10
    }
  }
}
```

> **From the Orchestrator Function, I am getting the following exception:**

```
"Failed to deserialize exception from TaskActivity: Unhandled exception while executing task: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Too many characters. The resulting number of bytes is larger than what can be returned as an int. (Parameter 'count')
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]    at System.Text.UTF32Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS encoder)
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]    at System.Text.UTF32Encoding.GetByteCount(String s)
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskExtension.GetIntputOutputTrace(String rawInputOutputData) in D:\a\r1\a\azure-functions-durable-extension\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\DurableTaskExtension.cs:line 1290
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.TaskActivityShim.RunAsync(TaskContext context, String rawInput) in D:\a\r1\a\azure-functions-durable-extension\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\Listener\TaskActivityShim.cs:line 75
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]    at DurableTask.Core.TaskActivityDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass13_1.<<OnProcessWorkItemAsync>b__2>d.MoveNext() in C:\source\durabletask\src\DurableTask.Core\TaskActivityDispatcher.cs:line 163
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]         at System.Text.UTF32Encoding.GetByteCount(Char* chars, Int32 count, EncoderNLS encoder)
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]    at System.Text.UTF32Encoding.GetByteCount(String s)
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableTaskExtension.GetIntputOutputTrace(String rawInputOutputData) in D:\a\r1\a\azure-functions-durable-extension\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\DurableTaskExtension.cs:line 1290
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.853Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.TaskActivityShim.RunAsync(TaskContext context, String rawInput) in D:\a\r1\a\azure-functions-durable-extension\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\Listener\TaskActivityShim.cs:line 75
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.DurableOrchestrationContext.CallDurableTaskFunctionAsync[TResult](String functionName, FunctionType functionType, Boolean oneWay, String instanceId, String operation, RetryOptions retryOptions, Object input, Nullable`1 scheduledTimeUtc) in D:\a\r1\a\azure-functions-durable-extension\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\ContextImplementations\DurableOrchestrationContext.cs:line 710
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.856Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.OutOfProcOrchestrationShim.ProcessAsyncActionsV2(AsyncAction[] actions) in D:\a\r1\a\azure-functions-durable-extension\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\Listener\OutOfProcOrchestrationShim.cs:line 200
[2022-05-05T06:23:31.856Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.OutOfProcOrchestrationShim.ReplayOOProcOrchestration(AsyncAction[][] actions, SchemaVersion schema) in D:\a\r1\a\azure-functions-durable-extension\src\WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask\Listener\OutOfProcOrchestrationShim.cs:line 222
```

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. Apparently the return values of activity functions have sever size limitations, rendering any heavier computation useless.